# search and delete cell elements in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array of doubles and string in which a particular column looks like this

```
abc = {[110;10];[20;110];[10];[220];[380];[15];[220];[110;15];[110;20];[110]};
```

I would like to delete all elements which are less than 110 and I tried this statement `abc(cellfun(@(x) any(x<110),abc),1) = [];`

I got an error A null assignment can have only one non-colon index. Could someone please explain and rectify this?

I expect the output to be like this

```
abc = {[110];[110];[];[220];[380];[];[220];[110];[110];[110]};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`abc = abc(~cellfun(@(x) any(x<110),abc),1)`?

That will invert the logical indices and then select the corresponding entries.

EDIT: After your comment was provided, that should do it:

```
abc_out = cellfun(@(x) x(x>=110), abc, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Comment: I expect the out put to be like this abc = {[110];[110];[];[220];[380];[];[220];[110];[110];[110]};

Comment: I guess with both our approaches if there is a value less than 110 the whole cell element is deleted instead of just the member which is less than 110.

Comment: Any will check `any` element of each cell-entry (i.e. submatrix), that means that won't get you the index of the corresponding sub-entry. So any won't help you much here then. So as a resumption: You simply want to keep the cell-structure and delete every element which is <110 on its own without touching anything else, right?

Comment: Ok I edited my answer, I hope I've got your desired output now  :-) Using `cellfun` with an anonymous function should do the trick here.